# Which potion can I use to cure slowness?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been bitten by a spider in Minecraft and now I am very slow. How do I stop this? I have drunk loads of milk and this does not work.

Comment: Are you using any mods? Because normal spiders do only normal damage while case spiders poison you. Neither slow you down.

Comment: Are you slow, or are you _hungry_? Hunger can stop you from running, which may seen like slowness!

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen, unless you are using a modded client. Spiders do normal damage while cave spiders poison you; neither of them slow you down. Check if your settings have changed to make it LOOK like you have slowed down?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a glitch unless your FOV has somehow dropped (I play at quake Pro) the only thing I can think of other than drinking a milk bucket is to spawn in a slowness potion and drinking it and THEN a milk bucket

Comment: This answer is not very helpful. :(  How does milk fix "slowness"?  Was that added in a patch or is this based on a mod?

Comment: A bucket of milk disables all position effects on a player when drunken @NBN-Alex

Comment: It's been like that for a while NBN-Alex , so yes that answer was helpful

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried drinking A bucket of milk? It nulls all effects of all potions

Comment: The question already states that that has been tried